# How can I highlight a line in TMemo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I would like to highlight the line that contains the caret in a `TMemo` control, similar to the editor in the Delphi IDE. I tried the following code and it kind of works:
(Sorry for the With-statement, this needs refactoring.)

```
procedure TMemo.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PS: TPaintStruct;
  DC: Hdc;
  Canvas: TCanvas;
  LineIdx: Integer;
  X, Y: Integer;
  Max: Integer;
  s: string;
  h: Integer;
begin
  DC := Message.DC;
  if DC = 0 then
    DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
  Canvas := TCanvas.Create;
  try
    Canvas.Handle := DC;
    Canvas.Font.Name := Font.Name;
    Canvas.Font.Size := Font.Size;
    with Canvas do begin
      Max := TopLine + VisibleLines;
      if Max > Pred(Lines.Count) then
        Max := Pred(Lines.Count);

      Brush.Color := Self.Color;
      FillRect(Self.ClientRect);

      Brush.Color := clYellow;
      h := Canvas.TextHeight('Mg');
      Y := (Line - TopLine) * h;
      Marker.Top := y + self.Top;
      FillRect(Rect(0, Y, ClientRect.Right, Y + h));
      Brush.Color := Self.Color;

      Y := 1;
      for LineIdx := TopLine to Max do begin
        X := 2;
        s := Lines[LineIdx];
        if LineIdx = Line then
          Brush.Color := clYellow
        else
          Brush.Color := Self.Color;
        TextOut(X, Y, s);
        Inc(Y, h);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if Message.DC = 0 then
      EndPaint(Handle, PS);
  end;
  Canvas.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

(This code is added to the memo through an interposer class.)

This works, but it isn't triggered often enough. E.g. when I scroll using the down arrow.

I could, of course now start adding all kinds of events in order to call the memo's invalidate method and so forcing a repaint, but that doesn't seem right. Maybe there is already such a component, that I could just use? I already checked `TJvMemo` from the `Jvcl` which doesn't seem to have such a feature.

Edit: I ended up using SynEdit.

Comment: `TMemo` is the wrong control. Are you tied to `TMemo`?

Comment: If you have the option, rather than `TMemo` maybe something like `SynEdit` would be a better choice?

Comment: I just looked at SynEdit but could not find an option for highlighting the current line. Maybe I overlooked it, it is a rather complex control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, TMemo is not a requirement, it just is what I usually use to display and edit multi line text.

Comment: Found it: TSynEdit.ActiveLineColor I must have been blind.

Comment: @dummzeuch I was fairly sure it supported it, but didn't have anything to hand to confirm it.

Comment: @Andy_D SynEdit is quite a lot more than I need and yet another component to add to the project. I would have preferred a more lightweight solution.

Comment: Hard to have it both ways. What you ask for is very complex. Hardly surprising that you end up with a powerful solution.

Comment: Just FYI: The Windows Edit control (the multi-line version is what TMemo wraps) does not support custom drawing, so any attempt to do more than what it already does is pretty much bound to fail. It should never be the preferred control for anything than simple display of multi-line content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TMemo` doesn't support that feature natively, and attempting to add that feature will lead to no end of headaches.

Instead, consider using a different text-editing control. That's what the Delphi IDE does. [SynEdit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synedit/), for example, supports the feature: Set the `ActiveLineColor` property to something other than `clNone`.

Answer (score 6):

**If** your question is about, ***how to 'Highlight on TMemo row (line) by selection'*** 
, here is your answer.

---

### Whole Line highlight by selection cause of Mouse Clicking on TMemo

```
Procedure SelectMemoLine(Memo : TCustomMemo) ;
Var LineNumber : Integer;
Begin
  LineNumber := Memo.Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, Memo.SelStart, 0);
  Memo.SelStart := Memo.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, LineNumber, 0);
  Memo.SelLength := Length(Memo.Lines[LineNumber]) ; 
  Memo.SetFocus;
End;

Procedure TMainForm.MemoActorClick(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  SelectMemoLine(MemoActor);
End;
```

---

### Whole Line highlight by selection cause of Scrolling Key Up-Down on TMemo

```
Procedure SelectMemoAtLine(Memo : TCustomMemo; LineNumber : Integer) ;
Begin
  Memo.SetFocus;
  Memo.SelStart := SendMessage(Memo.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, LineNumber, 0);
  Memo.SelLength := Length(Memo.Lines[LineNumber]);
End;

Procedure TMainForm.MemoActorKeyUp(Sender: TObject; Var Key: Word; 
                                   Shift: TShiftState);
Var LineNumber : Integer;
Begin
  Case Key of
    VK_UP, VK_DOWN : begin
      LineNumber := SendMessage(MemoActor.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, 
                                MemoActor.Selstart, 0);
      SelectMemoAtLine(MemoActor, LineNumber);
    end;
  end;
End;
```

The two methods are the same one use Memo.Perform(..) another one use SendMessage(Memo.Handle,..) and it is easy to combine together as one.
And, that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is simply to draw the user's attention to the text, consider simply coloring the text instaed of attempting highlighting

```
Memo1.SelStart  := 234;
Memo1.SelLength := 6;
Memo1.SelAttributes.Color := clGreen;
```

Comment: Does TMemo have property SelAttributes?

Answer (score 0):

when wordwrap in memo is true use this

```
Procedure TfrmMain.Memo1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   Line: Integer;
   wrap : boolean;
begin
   wrap := (Sender as TMemo).WordWrap;
   if wrap  then
    (Sender as TMemo).WordWrap := false;

   with (Sender as TMemo) do
   begin
     Line      := Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, SelStart, 0);
     SelStart  := Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, Line, 0);
     SelLength := Length(Lines[Line]);
   end;
  if wrap  then
    (Sender as TMemo).WordWrap := wrap;
end;
```